# How to construct a SQL query involving max values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following psql tables with the following columns:

```
Library:  
    library_id

Shelf:  
    shelf_id
    library_id (Library foreign key)
    forbidden = (boolean)

Author
    author_id 
    shelf_id (Shelf foreign key)
    number_pages_witten

Book
    book_id 
    author_id (Author foreign key)
    book_name
```

I need a query that retrieves the following back:

For library_id=5, get the list of book names from authors who have written the most pages per shelf, for all shelves that have "forbidden" = False

I have the following so far:

```
SELECT name FROM Book AS b 
INNER JOIN Author AS a
ON b.author_id = a.author_id
...
...
WHERE library_id=5
```

My sql syntax is very weak. I'm having trouble getting the author with the most number of pages on the shelf back and plug it into rest of the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement to get *"authors who have written the most pages per shelf, for all shelves that have "forbidden" = False"* is a classic usecase for the `rank()` window function. From there on, you just need an inner queries:

```
SELECT name
FROM   book b
WHERE  b.author_id IN (SELECT author_id 
                       FROM   (SELECT a.author_id, 
                               RANK() OVER 
                                      (PARTITION BY a.shelf_id 
                                       ORDER BY number_pages_written DESC) rk
                               FROM   author a
                               JOIN   shelf s ON a.shelf_id = a.shelf_id
                               WHERE  library_id = 5)
                       WHERE  rk = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query simultaneously retrieve **list of most pages book per author and per shelf**,

- At first, It's prepared a list of `Author Id`, `Shelf Id` and `Number Pages Written` by a self-join that has the same `Author Id` and `Shelf Id` but their `Number Pages Written` are different,
- Then, Group by `Author Id` and `Shelf Id`

I hope it can be helpful for your question and all relate issues

```
select author_id1, shelf_id1, max(num_pages1)
(
    select 
        Author1.author_id author_id1, Author1.shelf_id shelf_id1, Author1.number_pages_witten num_pages1,
        Author2.author_id author_id2, Author2.shelf_id shelf_id2, Author2.number_pages_witten num_pages2
    from Author Author1 left join Author Author2
        on Author1.author_id = Author2.author_id and Author1.shelf_id = Author2.shelf_id
        and Author1.number_pages_witten != Author2.number_pages_witten
)ds
group by author_id1, shelf_id1
```